# How to generate query in Django?

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

If I have a list of ID's to filter with, how can I generate the query? For example:

`[14, 44]` would result in `query.filter(tags__tag_id=14).filter(tags__tag_id=44)`

```
>>> print(Place.objects.filter(tags__tag_id=14).filter(tags__tag_id=44).query)

SELECT "places_place"."id", "places_place"."address"
FROM "places_place"
INNER JOIN "places_placetag"
ON ("places_place"."id" = "places_placetag"."place_id")
INNER JOIN "places_placetag"
T4 ON ("places_place"."id" = T4."place_id")
WHERE ("places_placetag"."tag_id" = 14 AND T4."tag_id" = 44)
```

(I don't know what the `T4` in the SQL above is but no matter, that's for another question)

I have a hacky solution in mind, but it's so naive and shitty-looking, there must be a better way to do it:

```
tag_ids = [14, 44]

query_string = 'Place.objects'
for tag_id in tag_ids:
    query_string += ('.filter(tags___tag_id=' + str(tag_id))

query = eval(query_string)
```

---

```
class Place(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=123)

class PlaceTag(models.Model):
    place = models.ForeignKey('Place', models.CASCADE, 'tags')
    tag = models.ForeignKey('Tag', models.CASCADE, 'places')

class Tag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=254)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
tag_ids = [11, 22, 33]  # Place must have all of these tags
query = Place.objects.all()
for tag_id in tag_ids:
    query = query.filter(tags___tag_id=tag_id)
```